# when I set content limit 0 the more link disappear in genesis why?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I want to display: content limit should be 0 and read more link also appear in Genesis. This is my code:

```
add_filter ( 'get_the_content_more_link', 'custom_read_more_link' );
function custom_read_more_link() {
    return '... <a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink () . '">Read More</a>';
}
```

If any one know the answer, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't give any code and your question isn't clear at all.

Comment: /* this is my code for read more link */                                                             add_filter( 'get_the_content_more_link', 'custom_read_more_link' );
function custom_read_more_link() {
    return '... <a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read More</a>';
}

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Dashboard** > **Genesis** > **Content Archive** and set **Display** option to **Entry excerpts**

Copy the following code to functions.php

```
//* Modify the length of post excerpts
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'sp_excerpt_length' );
function sp_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 0; // pull first 0 words
}
```

Comment: what else do you have in your functions.php? you don't need `custom_read_more_link' in functions.php any more.